# Google App Engine. Resize only big images with get_serving_url()

Tags: image, google-app-engine, image-scaling

I have created website where users can upload image with any size.

I have served images with `get_serving_url` function.
I have added to end of image modifiers to resize image to 200px size.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/img/dtrh0i6I_V5JGulg2_LKZw===s200
```

I have uploaded image 1000x800 - and all right - I have image with size 200x160

If I have uploaded image 100x50 - in result I have resized image with size 200x100. But this is not a good. I need to show **original small image**, if image size lower that 200px.

How to do this on Google App Engine + Python with `get_serving_url`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need can't be done automatically using `get_serving_url`.

I think the easiest way to implement that would be saving the image along with a `needs_resize` property and calling `get_serving_url` without `size` parameter if that is not the case (which serves the original image).

Comment: Yes, if I have not set =s200, than image shown in original size 100x50. But, in template I use url to image, and need to show correct image without additional logic in template.

Comment: Maybe I need to re-implement `/_ah/img/...` to show image in original size and ignore =sXX property, if image is lover than XX size?

Comment: Either you send the image URL to the template or call `get_serving_url` in the template. Write a wrapper around it. As I said, "only resize if bigger" type of logic is not built-in.

Comment: In this case I need to make query to blob store each time to retrieve information about image height and width?

Comment: @Anton How are you getting the URL in the first place? Store the image size alongside.

Comment: @Nick I have upload image separately, and after this attach blob key to another model instance. On this step I cant get size of image, because size of image (WxH) available only in uploading handler.

Comment: @Anton Then add size parameters to the model that stores the blob key.